# Using reserved / deprecated IPv6 ranges on older linux kernels

Tags: routing, ipv6, linux-kernel

I have an old Synology NAS with kernel 2.6.32.12.

And I use the Yggdrasil network, which uses the deprecated range 0200::/7 for addressing.

About the range 0200::/7:
http://www.iana.org/assignments/ipv6-address-space/ipv6-address-space.xhtml

About the Yggdrasil network:
https://yggdrasil-network.github.io/faq.html#will-yggdrasil-conflict-with-my-network-routing

Well, so, running Yggdrasil on some device, I get IPv6 from the range 0200::/7 and the routed subnet 0300::/64.

I can assign addresses from subnet 0300::/64 to other devices on my network without installing Yggdrasil on them. Access to 0200::/7 in such cases is configured by specifying a route (https://yggdrasil-network.github.io/configuration.html#advertising-a-prefix).

And it all works fine on newer devices, with new Linux kernels, in particular with the 5.4 kernel.

But on my old NAS with Linux kernel version 2.6, I cannot set such a route, receiving the message:
RTNETLINK answers: Invalid argument

I.e., in response to the command `ip -6 route add 200::/7 via 302:b9e3:7fcd:57c::1`, I get:
**RTNETLINK answers: Invalid argument**

(302:b9e3:7fcd:57c::1 is the address on another device where Yggdrasil is installed)

The same command on a device with a newer kernel works fine and adds the route.

There is no way to update the kernel on the NAS. At least, I do not know how. New versions of the DSM for my model are not being released.

I can run Yggdrasil directly on the NAS, in which case everything works fine. But my NAS has relatively little RAM, so I would like to access the network from it without installing Yggdrasil on it.

Is there any other way to specify a route using addresses from the reserved (deprecated) IPv6 range? Maybe is there some way to disable IPv6 address verification/validation?

Comment: Using invalid addressing is not the reasonable use of a business network. "_Questions should demonstrate reasonable information technology management practices. Questions that relate to unsupported hardware or software platforms or unmaintained environments may not be suitable for Server Fault._"

Comment: @ron-maupin, I'm just a network user, trying to use what I have. The technology itself currently works on modern devices with current versions of linux kernels. The problem is only with old devices.

Comment: But why is your business trying to use invalid addressing?

Comment: At this stage, I'm just exploring the possibilities of this network and find the technology interesting and very promising.

Comment: I still do not think it meets the "_reasonable information technology management practices_" requirement for [sf].